# Bash script for changing cpu minimal frequency OPERATION NOT PERMITTED

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, performance, cpu

I wrote a script to set the minimum cpu frequency in the bash, looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Processor min-freq"
echo -n Zadej minimální frekvenci procesoru
read val
echo $val > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq
echo $val > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq
echo $val > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq
echo $val > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq
echo $val > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq
echo $val > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq
echo "all done"
```

but it does not work, this is the output from the terminal:

```
gandalf@gandalf-MS-7693 ~ $ sudo -s
gandalf-MS-7693 ~ # '/home/gandalf/Plocha/procesor-min-freq.sh' 
Processor min-freqZadej minimální frekvenci procesoru1500000
/home/gandalf/Plocha/procesor-min-freq.sh: řádek 5: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq: Operation not permitted
/home/gandalf/Plocha/procesor-min-freq.sh: řádek 6: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq: Operation not permitted
/home/gandalf/Plocha/procesor-min-freq.sh: řádek 7: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq: Operation not permitted
/home/gandalf/Plocha/procesor-min-freq.sh: řádek 8: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq: Operation not permitted
/home/gandalf/Plocha/procesor-min-freq.sh: řádek 9: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq: Operation not permitted
/home/gandalf/Plocha/procesor-min-freq.sh: řádek 10: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq: Operation not permitted
all done
gandalf-MS-7693 ~ #
```

Do you have any ideas?
I will be great for the solution

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed,** cause found in file: `/etc/cpufreqd.conf`
I rewrote the profile frequency: Performance High, originally there was:

```
[Profile]
Name = Performance High
Minfreq = 100%
Maxfreq = 100%
Policy = performance
# Exec_post = echo 8> / proc / acpi / sony / brightness
[/ Profile]
```

After replacing:

```
[Profile]
Name = Performance High
Minfreq = 0%
Maxfreq = 100%
Policy = performance
# Exec_post = echo 8> / proc / acpi / sony / brightness
[/ Profile]
```

It is after the problem, parade :)

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you are using the intel p-state governors, execute the command

`sudo cpupower frequency-set -d 1500kHz`

If you are not using intel_pstate, then

`sudo apt install cpufrequtils`

will download a set of utilities, and

`sudo cpufreq-set -d 1500kHz`

will set the minimum frequency

Comment: No, my CPU is the AMD FX-6100, I use a program called indicator-cpufreq to set the cpu frequency. I do not know why, but after restarting the PC, the minimum frequency will always be up to a maximum of 3300000. I always solved it by opening the above mentioned file with the roots in nano and all overwriting, so I wanted to write a script that will speed up.

Comment: if you execute `cpupower frequency-info` does it provide any output?

Comment: No, only this: <code>gandalf@gandalf-MS-7693 ~ $ cpupower frequency-info
WARNING: cpupower not found for kernel 4.10.0-32

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-4.10.0-32-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-4.10.0-32-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-generic
</code>

Comment: Added section to answer fro cpufrequtils

Comment: It looks like it worked, but in fact it does not do anything. Files in: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scalling_min_freq etc. Are still the same.

Comment: Well, now it works, just use the command sudo cpufreq-set -f and it works. Now I'll try what it will do when I restart.

Comment: Aha, so after the restart, the command: `code` cpufreq-set -d 1400000`code` does not work
  But interestingly, when I manually overwrite all the files, it suddenly starts working.

Comment: The specified frequency may need to be some specific value allowed by your processors

Comment: Frequency 1400000, the processor certainly allows, but after each restart, the minimum frequency itself is overwritten to a maximum value of 3300000 and the CPU thus goes unnecessarily to full power.